# Covering function inside callback function with jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am developing a Nodejs app. I am using muter for uploading file. When I write unit tests with jest, I see functions cover in test coverage. It shows I have uncovered lines. The problem is those functions are helper functions inside constructor options

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: "uploads/",
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    filterFilename(req, file, cb);
  }
});
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    files: 2,
    fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024
  },
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    checkFileType(file, cb);
  }
});
```

I want to know how to test `filterFilename` and `checkFileType` function as well as statements inside them. By the way, those functions are private functions. I don't want to export them.

Answer (score 0):

One way to test this code would be to mock `multer` like so:

```
var multer  = require('multer')
jest.mock('multer', () => jest.fn())

test('basic', () => {
  runTheCodeInYourSnippet();
  expect(multer).toHaveBeenCalled()
  const {
    storage,
    fileFilter
  } = multer.mock.calls[0][0]

  // test storage.filename(req, file, cb)
  // and fileFilter(req, file, cb)
})
```